# String to Class: Conversion Class or Base Conversion Method?

Tags: class, delphi, model, delphi-2009

I'm working on a project where I builded a structure composed by a basic class "TFuncao", two descendant classes "TSolicitacao", "TResposta" and as many as needed descendant classes, all of them are class-like-models only with properties.

The first one is the focus of this question, it has a method "ParaTexto" that returns a string of all its properties in a specific way (basically converting them to string).
That "TSolicitacao" class has many descendant and each one has the method "ParaTexto" calling its ancestor function and adding its own properties.

So, my question is:

Should I keep this method "ParaTexto"? Or remove it and create a class with a method that receives a "TSolicitacao" and accordingly to its type (a descendent class) returns a string?

I thought of this because a model class technically should have only getters and setters.

Code - the getters and setters where removed to save space:

"TFuncao" class file:

```
unit Funcao;

interface

uses
  Funcao.Tipo;

type
  TFuncao = class abstract
  private
    FFUNCAO: TFuncaoTipo;
    FSEQUENC: string;
    procedure SetFUNCAO(const Value: TFuncaoTipo);
    procedure SetSEQUENC(const Value: string);
  published
    property SEQUENC: string read FSEQUENC write SetSEQUENC;
    property FUNCAO: TFuncaoTipo read FFUNCAO write SetFUNCAO;
    constructor Create; virtual;
  end;
```

"TSolicitacao" class file:

```
unit Funcao.Solicitacao;

interface

uses
  Funcao;

type
  TSolicitacao = class abstract (TFuncao)
  published
    function ParaTexto: string; virtual;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Funcoes,
  SysUtils;

{ TSolicitacao }

function TSolicitacao.ParaTexto: string;
begin
  Result :=
    Copy(CompletarComEspacoAEsquerda(SEQUENC, 4), 1, 4) +
    Completar0AEsquerda(IntToStr(Integer(FUNCAO)), 2);
end;

end.
```

"TVendaSolicitacao" class file - a descendant class example of "TSolicitacao":

```
unit Venda.Solicitacao;

interface

uses
  Funcao.Solicitacao,
  Funcao.Tipo,
  Venda.Solicitacao.Produto;

type
  TVendaSolicitacao = class (TSolicitacao)
  private
    FNUMFISCAL: Integer;
    FNUMPDV: Integer;
    FAUTORIZ: string;
    FCONV_TIPO: Integer;
    FProdutos: TVendaSolicitacaoProdutoList;
    procedure SetAUTORIZ(const Value: string);
    procedure SetCONV_TIPO(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetNUMFISCAL(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetNUMPDV(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetProdutos(const Value: TVendaSolicitacaoProdutoList);
  published
    property NUMPDV: Integer read FNUMPDV write SetNUMPDV;
    property NUMFISCAL: Integer read FNUMFISCAL write SetNUMFISCAL;
    property AUTORIZ: string read FAUTORIZ write SetAUTORIZ;
    property CONV_TIPO: Integer read FCONV_TIPO write SetCONV_TIPO;
    property Produtos: TVendaSolicitacaoProdutoList read FProdutos write SetProdutos;
    function ParaTexto: string; override;
    constructor Create; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils,
  Funcoes;

{ TVendaSolicitacao }

constructor TVendaSolicitacao.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FUNCAO := ftVenda;
  FProdutos := TVendaSolicitacaoProdutoList.Create;
end;

function TVendaSolicitacao.ParaTexto: string;
begin
  Result :=
    inherited +
    Completar0AEsquerda(NUMPDV, 4) +
    Completar0AEsquerda(NUMFISCAL, 6) +
    Completar0AEsquerda(AUTORIZ, 12) +
    IntToStr(CONV_TIPO);

  if Produtos.Count > 0 then
    Result := Result + #13#10 + Produtos.ParaTexto;
end;

end.
```

"TConversao" class file - as I see it:

```
unit Conversao;

interface

uses
  Funcao;

type
  TConversao = class
  published
    function ParaTexto(Funcao: TFuncao): string;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Solicitacao,
  Solicitacao.Venda,
  Funcoes;

function ParaTexto(Funcao: TFuncao): string;
begin
  Result := '';

  if (Funcao is TSolicitacao) then
    Result :=
      Copy(CompletarComEspacoAEsquerda((Funcao as TSolicitacao).SEQUENC, 4), 1, 4) +
      Completar0AEsquerda(IntToStr(Integer((Funcao as TSolicitacao).FUNCAO)), 2);

  if (Funcao is TVendaSolicitacao) then
  begin
    Result :=
      inherited +
      Completar0AEsquerda((Funcao as TVendaSolicitacao).NUMPDV, 4) +
      Completar0AEsquerda((Funcao as TVendaSolicitacao).NUMFISCAL, 6) +
      Completar0AEsquerda((Funcao as TVendaSolicitacao).AUTORIZ, 12) +
      IntToStr((Funcao as TVendaSolicitacao).CONV_TIPO);

    if Produtos.Count > 0 then
      Result := Result + #13#10 + Produtos.ParaTexto;
  end;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you call 'children' are usually called descendants and what you call parent is 'ancestor'. Please correct it, these are two different concepts, very confusing.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I put the code for example and concrete application of what I'm asking.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Now I see, thank you for the tip

Comment: @YuriyAfanasenkov Thank you for the information. Changes already made.

Comment: I've updated my answer, added example how to use RTTI in your case. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should keep this method, in this way code is much more readable and reusable. Say, you defined new descendant of TSolicitacao, you override ParaTexto and that's it. All changes are in one place - in your class definition.

You could also try to use RTTI to iterate through all properties of class and make string automatically.

**UPDATE**

Some hints how you can use RTTI (working example). You define different types of integers:

```
  T7digitsInt = type Int64;
  T8digitsInt = type Int64;
```

Also, function type for conversion from Int64 to string:

```
TConvertCustomIntToStringProc = function (num: Int64): string;
```

Some test class which have properties, something like your TSolicitacao:

```
  TEntry = class (TObject)
    private
      fPlainInt: Int64;
      f7digitInt: T7digitsInt;
      fWriteOnlyInt: T7digitsInt;
      f8digitInt: T8digitsInt;
    published
      property PlainInt: Int64 read fPlainInt write fPlainInt;
      property NotSoPlainInt: T7digitsInt read f7digitInt write f7digitInt;
      property AnotherInt: T7digitsInt write fWriteOnlyInt;
      property Biggest: T8digitsInt read f8digitInt write f8digitInt;
  end;
```

Also, we declare global variable in our unit, this is list of different property types:

```
var PropertyConverters: TDictionary<string, TConvertCustomIntToStringProc>;
```

Now, in implementation section we define some functions which convert integer to string:

```
function ShowPlainInt64(num: Int64): string;
begin
    Result:=IntToStr(num);
end;

function Show7digitsInt(num: Int64): string;
begin
    Result:=Format('%.7d',[num]);
end;
```

We 'register' this functions to handle Int64 and T7DigitsInt respectively, somewhere in initialization, for example in TForm1.create:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PropertyConverters:=TDictionary<string,  ConvertCustomIntToStringProc>.Create;
  PropertyConverters.Add('Int64',ShowPlainInt64);
  PropertyConverters.Add('T7digitsInt',Show7DigitsInt);
end;
```

In TForm1.FormShow we create instance of TEntry and populate it with values to test our convertor, and then try to access them, iterating through properties:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var entry: TEntry;
    ctx : TRttiContext;
    rt : TRttiType;
    prop : TRttiProperty;
    convertProc: TConvertCustomIntToStringProc;
begin
  entry:=TEntry.Create;
  entry.PlainInt:=12;
  entry.NotSoPlainInt:=34;

  //iterating through all the properties with RTTI
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
    try
        rt := ctx.GetType(entry.ClassType);

        for prop in rt.GetProperties() do begin
          if prop.IsReadable then
            if PropertyConverters.TryGetValue(prop.PropertyType.Name,convertProc) then
              Memo1.Lines.Add(prop.Name+'='+convertProc(prop.GetValue(entry).AsOrdinal))
            else
              Memo1.lines.Add(prop.Name+':unregistered type')
          else
            Memo1.Lines.Add(prop.Name+':write-only');



        end;
    finally
        ctx.Free();
    end;

end;
```

That's what I got:

```
PlainInt=12
NotSoPlainInt=0000034
AnotherInt:write-only
Biggest:unregistered type
```

As you see, we have several integers, they just have different type and we made them show differently because of that. If there are not so many types, than code like that could be very efficient.

Comment: Yeah, It's more readable and reusable.
When I thought in this idea I was focusing on the model class type concept and leaving this classes only with information, since it will be used across the system, and there will be few times where the method will be needed.

I didin't used RTTI because the properties need to be converted in a specific way, example: the CONV_CODIGO must be converted to a string with 7 character and "0" (zero) on the left if its size is different than 7, not just plain conversion.

Comment: You can define several synonym types for Integer as it's made for example for TColor, and then define different rules how to show them, so if there are not so many different rules, you'll be able to collect properties into one string automatically. Delphi object inspector gives some clue what you can do with RTTI. For example, FileName is nothing more then just a string, but it's different type with rule binded how to show and change it.  But of course, writing each ParaTexto manually is most flexible

Comment: The field would be of a custom class, and in this class would be its ParaTexto method?
An ideia that I had: I thought on creating a class type with the order of the field one the file, its length, and its process to convert from whatever type to string (a function pointer or something similar). But it would take more time and maintenance to keep this structure, and at some point I would have to create each field and give its position, size, and function.

Comment: @LuizCarlosM.Jr. I'm new to this site, i'd like to ask: do you get inbox message when I comment your question without starting it with @username? Problem is: I answered some questions recently and then updated the answers adding some details and maybe topic starters just wasn't notified about this.

Comment: In my INBOX there is the comment that you added on my question and this answer to my question. I don't remember if I was notified about the commentaries in your answer, but in this last where you wrote "@LuizCarlosM.Jr." there was a new item in the INBOX menu.